# How to disable Cosmic Panda on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I enabled Cosmic Panda on YouTube to try it out. I seem unable to view *any* videos with it (in Chrome!) so want to disable it. I can't find settings for it anywhere and usefully Google search turns up a load of YouTube videos to show how to turn it off... helpful!

Any ideas how I disable it? I was logged in at the time so it's not in a cookie - it must be buried somewhere in the settings - anyone know where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is navigate to http://www.youtube.com/cosmicpanda and click the link called `older version`

Another way out is to navigate to http://www.youtube.com/testtube and follow the link to Cosmic Panda from there.

Comment: Woop- thanks! Unfortunately that doesn't appear to be why my YouTube videos are all coming up with an error...