# Why won't a YouTube video found in search show in Uploaded Videos?

Tags: youtube

I found a video, [You Ask- PM Netanyahu Answers!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrtHihxywTE), and it comes up in search too.

But I don't see it in the main channel uploads.

Why would it not appear there?

Is there a way to really display all of a channel's uploads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear:
[image]

I found it by going to http://www.youtube.com/user/IsraeliPM , clicked on [Videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/IsraeliPM/videos) and then on [Uploads](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUnQNAfkb4d08).

The above works for the new interface. For the old one, see below:

1. From your link, click on [IsraeliPM](http://www.youtube.com/user/IsraeliPM) below the video[image]
2. Click on **Uploads** above the video [image]
3. Scroll the list on the left to about the middle and you will find it [image]

Comment: I can't see a videos link and clicking the one you mention http://www.youtube.com/user/IsraeliPM/videos says the link appears to be broken. But I see an uploads option, I click it and just see  http://img807.imageshack.us/img807/7159/fsfsn.jpg     your uploads link that links to a playlist is good, how did you find that? here is all i see under playlists when I click it http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/4924/fafafak.jpg

Comment: I have the new interface, but I found your video on the old one as well. I'll update the post.

Comment: how do I view the old interface, and how do I view the new interface, switching between?  And now I see it halfway, but how do I sort by date? I see it is halfway down, but it's 1 month old and it's below ones that are 7 months old.  and how did you get your playlist link?

Comment: The old interface is the one you are seeing (the one from your screenshots). The new one is in a rollout phase. Enable/disable it see this question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/how-to-disable-cosmic-panda-on-youtube

Comment: ok if I don't do the new one. how do I get all uploads shown and sorted by date?(that video which is 1 month old still appears below 7 month old ones)  and how would I have found that playlist link via the regular interface?

Comment: By clicking on the **Date added** sorter link above the list. However, the first videos that appear in that list seem to be _featured_ - if you look closer, you will see that the background color around them is slightly different from the rest. After that batch, the rest are listed chronologically. I don't know how to find that list via the regular interface.

Comment: well spotted.. that's pretty good.. just changed to the newer interface, shame that great list doesn't display the date.. but at least it shows them all and pretty nicely